# Can I stream data from a writer to a reader in golang?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, bytebuffer

I want to process a number of files whose contents don't fit in the memory of my worker. The solution I found so far involves saving the results to the processing to the `/tmp` directory before uploading it to S3.

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/korovkin/limiter"
    "github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/parquet"
    "github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/writer"
)

func DownloadWarc(
    ctx context.Context,
    s3Client *s3.Client,
    warcs []*types.Warc,
    path string,
) error {
    key := fmt.Sprintf("parsed_warc/%s.parquet", path)

    filename := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s", path)
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating file: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    bytesWriter := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    pw, err := writer.NewParquetWriterFromWriter(bytesWriter, new(Page), 4)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Can't create parquet writer: %s", err)
    }

    pw.RowGroupSize = 128 * 1024 * 1024 //128M
    pw.CompressionType = parquet.CompressionCodec_SNAPPY

    mutex := sync.Mutex{}
    numWorkers := runtime.NumCPU() * 2
    fmt.Printf("Using %d workers\n", numWorkers)
    limit := limiter.NewConcurrencyLimiter(numWorkers)

    for i, warc := range warcs {
        limit.Execute(func() {
            log.Printf("%d: %+v", i, warc)
            body, err := GetWarc(ctx, s3Client, warc)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error getting warc: %s", err)
                return
            }

            page, err := Parse(body)
            if err != nil {
                key := fmt.Sprintf("unparsed_warc/%s.warc", path)
                s3Client.PutObject(
                    ctx,
                    &s3.PutObjectInput{
                        Body:   bytes.NewReader(body),
                        Bucket: &s3Record.Bucket.Name,
                        Key:    &key,
                    },
                )
                fmt.Printf("error getting page %s: %s", key, err)
                return
            }

            mutex.Lock()
            err = pw.Write(page)
            pw.Flush(true)
            mutex.Unlock()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error writing page: %s", err)
                return
            }
        })
    }

    limit.WaitAndClose()
    err = pw.WriteStop()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error writing stop: %s", err)
    }
    bytesWriter.Flush()

    file.Seek(0, 0)
    _, err = s3Client.PutObject(
        ctx,
        &s3.PutObjectInput{
            Body:   file,
            Bucket: &s3Record.Bucket.Name,
            Key:    &key,
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error uploading warc: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Is there a way to avoid saving the contents into a temp file and use only a limited size byte buffer between the writer and the upload function?

In other words can I begin to stream data to a reader while still writing to the same buffer?

Comment: Like [this](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy)?

Comment: You can use a pipe. If you can show in the code which part does the large read, as it is not clear.

Comment: [`io.Pipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Pipe) _`Pipe creates a synchronous in-memory pipe. It can be used to connect code expecting an io.Reader with code expecting an io.Writer`_

Comment: @tkausl `io.Copy` copies from reader to writer, I want to pipe from writer to reader

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't read from a writer and you can't write to a reader.

Comment: I want to pipe what I just wrote to the writer, to a reader

Comment: @JimB you seem to be in the right direction but the reader reaches EOF if I'm not writing to the pipe fast enough

Comment: @JaderDias: that's not how pipes work. The read side will block if the writer falls behind. You don't get EOF until you close the writer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to write the same content to multiple writers. Using [`io.MultiWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) might allow you to not use a temp file. However, it might still be good to use a temp file.

I often use [`io.MultiWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) to write to a list of checksum (sha256...) calculators. Actually, last time I read the the S3 client code, I noticed it does this under the hood to calculate the checksum. MultiWriter is pretty useful for piping big files between cloud places.

Also, if you end up using temp files. You may want to use [`os.CreateTemp`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#CreateTemp) to create temporary files. If you don't, you may run into issues with your created file names if your code is running in two processes or your files have the same name.

Feel free to clarify your question. I can try to answer again :)